# How do I setup SSH/SFTP on two systems to transfer files between them?

Tags: ssh

I have two computers connected using a virtual private network, but now I need to create a SSH so I can transfer files. How do I do this? Both computers are running Ubuntu.

Comment: Refer to this. [Guide SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring)

Comment: `apt-get install openssh` is not enough for you? Why do you need to build it?

Comment: @Jakuje - I am very new to Linux and not familiar with all the commands necessary to navigating and installing certain features, etc.. But your information is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Try [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/)

```
rsync -avz /origin/path/ username@69.69.69.60:/destination/path/
```